# How do I properly call a non-return-value Swift function when it also has an overloading version that has returned value?

Tags: swift

Say I have the following function definition:

```
func doSomething() {
    print("do something")
}

func doSomething() -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

and I want to call the one that has no returned value, if I do this:

```
doSomething()
```

I get the error `Ambiguous use of 'doSomething()'`.

I have to do this:

```
let _:Void = doSomething()
```

to make the compiler happy, but this does not seem very elegant, so how can I do it elegantly?

Comment: "*so how can I do it elegantly*" - avoid having two functions with the same name that only differ by return type.

Comment: @rmaddy That is true. In my case it also makes sense to name the functions the same, so I came up with this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you discovered, you can guide type inferencing to use the overload that returns `Void` by suppling a type. The other way to supply a type for type inferencing is to use the `as` keyword. In your case, it would read `doSomething() as Void`.